# How to webpack a node_module for use in both React and ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack

I'm building out a library that will be used by both a React Native project and a React project as a node_module hosted on my github.

This is proving quite daunting- and based on how ugly my code has become, I feel I must be doing something wrong.

Here's the presenting problem, the most recent issue:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/plenti-api/src/services/AccountService.ts 11:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| export default class AccountService {
>   private client: IClient
|   constructor(client: IClient) {
|     this.client = client
```

This is occurring when trying to build the React project via `npm start`. The project successfully builds and runs on the React Native side of things.

what do I need to put in my `.tsconfig` / `.webpack.config.js` / `somethingelse` in order to allow for these typescript structures to exist in my library and be imported correctly into my web project?

Comment: You're asking Node to load a TypeScript file (`AccountService.ts`) but Node has no idea what TypeScript is. It only knows JavaScript and JSON, and plain JS doesn't have a `private` keyword (in fact, it doesn't have _any_ mechanism that allows you to specify private class properties in the current version of the spec).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans hmm... sounds promising. The rest of the application is written in typescript. So why does `npm start` know how to build typescript that is in the project, but not in `node_modules` (presumably). And which configuration would I mess with to get Node to be able to read TypeScript?

Comment: The obvious answer there would be "because your `start` script probably includes a compile pass that turns TS into JS first", but without you showing your npm scripts, no one can say.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans in that case- does the goal become to get the module I'm writing to compile to javascript before it gets installed as a `node_module`?

Comment: Given that Node only knows how to natively run JS: absolutely. Work in TS as much as you want, but as publication target, your module should be JS so that it will run on any system that has Node, and just Node, installed.

Comment: Want to give a shoutout to this guide if anyone in the future has this problem https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/writing-a-node-module-in-typescript.html

Comment: Note that future visitors are unlikely to find posts without answers, so you'll probably want to write your own answer if you think that'll help future visitors. (and yes, that's indeed quite a nice article)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike in the comments, figured out it's because node needs to be written in vanilla javascript and therefore `node_modules` need to be built so that can be imported by pure javascript.

This article https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/writing-a-node-module-in-typescript.html was very helpful in achieving that task.